# How to optimize the code as synchronized block causing a lot of delay while processing multiple requests

Tags: mysql, database, locking, consistency

I am working on some code where I have an inventory table which has items **A, B, C** with quantity say **2,1,2**

Now multiple users can call my `order` function which will check the inventory status and then the order will be complete if only all the items in the order are available.

For example we have `order(A:2, B:1)`. This order can be completed as items are present in inventory. But if we have order(A:2, B:2) then it is not possible to meet the order and we can throw an exception.

Now the above is easy is in single request systems. But practically we will be having many concurrent order requests say user1 calls `order(A:2, B:1)` and user2 calls `order(B:1, C:2)` then only one order can be met as **B** item is part of both the orders and the available quantity(1) is less than combined ordered quantity(2).

First I thought of the following code:

```
    Class Order{
      Map<String, Integer> requestedProducts;
    }

    // synchronize the order object as we need to have a consistent view of the available inventory
Class test {
    public void order(Order o){    
       synchronized(Order.class) {
         // do the database operations
       }
    }
   }
```

The obvious drawback of above method is that lock on Order object is not optimal.

**Is there any other optimal way of achieving the same that is either the complete order can be completed or if atleast one item is missing the order fails?**

I can think of the following two other ways after reading some articles on google:

- using transactions with some suitable isolation level like **Read
  committed** which ensures that current transaction at the end checks
  whether any other transaction has not committed the same data that we
  are modifying.
- I can just use **MYSQL row level lock** along with **for update** locking
  clause. Also pls let me know whether db level locking is better compared to code level locking as was done in the code?

Answer (score 0):

I was just looking at many different resources to find solution to above and I think the best solution is to **start a transaction and use a Row level lock depending on the number of products that are requested in the order**.

So there is no need to have a synchronized lock which is a JVM level lock and if there are multiple instances of our website running then the synchronized locking mechanism fails.
So using transaction and row level lock the code(pseudo code) may look like the following:

```
 while(restart the transaction if some error occurs such as timeout)
    begin transaction;
    String query = "select * from inventory where";
    for each(product in requested products){

      String productId = product.getProductId();
      query += "productid = "+productId;

      if(!lastProduct) {
        query += "OR"
      }
    }
    query += "FOR UPDATE";

   // will lead to lock on the rows  due to FOR UPDATE
    Resultset rs = execute(query);

    forEach(reuslt in resultSet){

     if(requested quantity available)
        update inventory with updated quantity for the product type in current result of resultSet
    }
}
```

IMHO locking is required in this as I am not aware of any other better way given the conditions(all items must be present to complete the order). So we need to ensure first that items are present and also need to ensure that no other transaction updates the same inventory record we just read in order to ensure consistency.

Kindly let me know if there is any other better way.